# React-native SectionList Item index to continue between sections

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Following along RN [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) docs. If I want to build an homogeneous sectionlist like in the example:

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item, index}) => <ListItem title={item} index={index} />}
  renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Header title={section.title} />}
  sections={[ // homogeneous rendering between sections
    {data: [...], title: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ...},
    {data: [...], title: ...},
  ]}
/>
```

How do I make `index` to continue between sections? As it is right now, [`index` reflects the Item's index within the section](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/sectionlist.md#sections). For each section the `index` starts from zero. Is there any other way to have an index that progresses from the first item of the first section to the last item of the last section. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As of RN 0.52 there is no solution just by leveraging the `SectionList`.
Obviously, we can obtain the desired result by other means.

I managed to have indexes flowing from the first to last section, item by item with a quick vanilla JS workaround:

1. create an array of all items
2. get the index of the item that matches the result of an `array.find()`
3. display the index

Here are a couple of lines from my solution:

N.B. I'm taking advantage of my particular `item`'s shape which is an obj with an `id` prop. But it's easy to generalize. `sections` and `items` are arrays of obj.

```
 const Item = ({ item, itemsList }) => {
const foundItem = itemsList.find(i => i === item.id); // find the match
const itemIndex = itemsList.indexOf(foundItem); // get its index

return (
    <View>
        <Text>{itemIndex + 1}</Text>
    </View>
);
};

const Section = ({ section }) => (
 <View>
     <Text>{section.name}</Text>
 </View>
 );

 class List extends Component {
  renderList() {
    // create the `data` prop required for `SectionList` which contains `items`
    const dataSource = sections.map(s => {
        const { items, name } = s;
        return Object.assign({}, { name, key: s.id, data: items });
    });

    // create an array with all items' ids
    const itemsList = _.chain(sections)
        .map(s => s.items.map(item => item.id))
        .flatten()
        .value();

    return (
        <SectionList
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Item item={item} itemsList={itemsList} />
            )}
            renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
                <Section section={section} />
            )}
            sections={dataSource} // must provide a nested array of obj with a `data` prop
            keyExtractor={item => item.id} // key for the nested array (items)
        />
    );
}

render() {
    return <View>{this.renderList()}</View>;
}
}
```